# How to make a player look at the other player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I and my friends are doing a maze minigame and there's a killer, when the killer is 1 block of distance from the other player (a survivor) the survivor is going to look at the killer, but the only problem is that I don't know how to do that, I made the command to detect when the player distance is less or equals one (..1) but yeah, idk how to make the player look at the killer, we use tags, and when the distance is ..1 it's not just gonna make the player face the killer but also, play a 10 second audio (Slender death sound) and in that time everyone is gonna have slowness (the killer and the player), please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Teleport a player to face an entity?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220865/teleport-a-player-to-face-an-entity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/tp` has such a feature:

```
/execute as @p at @s run tp @s ~ ~ ~ facing entity <selector>
```

Note that teleporting a player every tick makes their movement very jittery and hard to control for the player.